# To remove a tag from a xml file

Tags: text-processing, xml

My file contains data which is not well idented.
Say like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><ns0:collection
xmlns:ns0="http://namspace/Service/1.0"><Record>
.
.</Record></ns0:collection>
```

I have to marge file N number of such files and create one file. So I need the following to be done:

1. I need to remove only `</ns0:collection>` closing tag from the first file
2. remove both `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><ns0:collection xmlns:ns0="http://namspace/Service/1.0">` and  `</ns0:collection>` in the next (n-1) files
3. Have to remove only `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><ns0:collection xmlns:ns0="http://namspace/Service/1.0">` in the last file and merge all of them together

I have tried using `sed` command to process first file which is not resulting anything, "merged.xml" is empty.

```
sed '/<\/ns0:collection>/d' $file1 > merged.xml
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: extend your input showing actual `Record` nodes

Comment: This actually sounds like an XY problem - you don't want to delete tags from your XML, you want to merge some files.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't specify that you could only use `sed`, so if you have access to `xml_grep` (see [Merge multiple XML files from commend line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004135/merge-multiple-xml-files-from-command-line), second answer), I would recommend that because it does a lot of the heavy work for you and for a simple merge job like this can be done in one command:

```
xml_grep --cond Record --wrap "ns0:collection" --descr 'xmlns:ns0="http://namespace/Service/1.0"' --encoding "UTF-8" *.xml
```

Test files:

test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><ns0:collection
xmlns:ns0="http://namespace/Service/1.0""><Record>
Test
</Record></ns0:collection>
```

test1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><ns0:collection
xmlns:ns0="http://namespace/Service/1.0"><Record>
Test 1<a>a</a><b c="c">d</b>
</Record></ns0:collection>
```

Result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ns0:collection xmlns:ns0="http://namespace/Service/1.0">
<Record>
Test 1<a>a</a><b c="c">d</b></Record><Record>
Test
</Record>
</ns0:collection>
```

I prefer to use XML-aware tools when dealing with XML files, because the chance of messing up the structure with `sed` and friends is quite high and you can easily end up with a malformed XML document!

Comment: Agreed. XML is a contextual language, and regular expressions  ... aren't. They're always going to be a bit hacky.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions:

1. I need to remove only  closing tag from the first file, solution:

   ```
   sed -i.bak -e 's/<\/ns0:collection>/ /' -e 's/<\/Record>/ /' n0
   ```
2. remove both `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><ns0:collection xmlns:ns0="http://namspace/Service/1.0">` and `</ns0:collection>` in the next (n-1) files:

   ```
   sed -i.bak -e 's/<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8 ?>.*<ns0:collection/ /' -e 's/xmlns.*/ /' -e 's/<\/R.*>.*>/ /' n1
   ```

   - Doing so for file name range:

     ```
     find . -type f -name "n[1-3]" -exec sed i.bak -e 's/<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8 ?>.*<ns0:collection/ /' -e 's/xmlns.*/ /' -e 's/<\/R.*>.*>/ /' {} \;
     ```
3. Have to remove only  in the last file and merge all of them together:

   ```
   sed i.bak -e 's/<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8 ?>.*<ns0:collection/ /' -e 's/xmlns.*/ /' ne
   ```

Then finaly join them:

```
cat n0 n[1-3] ne > joined
```

I used the following files: `n0`,`n1`, `n2`, `n3`, and `ne`. I added the following text into each:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><ns0:collection
xmlns:ns0="http://namspace/Service/1.0"><Record>
hello from nigeria
</Record></ns0:collection>
```

The resulting file `joined` was as seen below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><ns0:collection
xmlns:ns0="http://namspace/Service/1.0"><Record>
hello from nigeria



hello from nigeria



hello from nigeria



hello from nigeria



hello from nigeria
</Record></ns0:collection>
```

**Note:**

1. I see from the first problem you need to remove both `</Record></ns0:collection>` not just `</ns0:collection>`. So I took the liberty to do, else we would have a duplicate `</Record>` entry when the files are merged.
2. The filenames here would have to be modified by you so you can run one command over them all, here I used `n[1-3]`. Pick that which works best for you.
3. **PLEASE RUN A TEST FIRST AND SEE THE RESULTS**, here I used `i.bak` so `sed` creates a backup automatically.

Comment: Please note you didn't provide any text between so to help you, you need to include the texts between those nodes so I change the sed command accordingly. I sed my own texts to show how I might do what your asking so update your information so we can be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that using `sed` isn't good for processing XML, and instead using a parser.

I would also suggest that you have an XY problem here - it's not about deleting tags, but rather merging XML files.

Personally - I like `perl` and `XML::Twig`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#load the parser
use XML::Twig; 

#get our file list - we use the "first" file as the basis.
#can use sort on this list if desired. 
my ( $first_file, @other_files ) = glob ( 'C://tmp//xmltest/*.xml' ); 

#Our 'parent' document. 
my $doc = XML::Twig -> new -> parsefile ( $first_file ); 


foreach my $file ( @other_files ) { 
   my $mergedoc = XML::Twig -> new -> parsefile ( $file ); 

   #//Record means any <Record> node anywhere in the tree. 
   foreach my $record ( $mergedoc -> get_xpath ( '//Record' ) ) {
      $record -> cut;
      #paste it into our parent doc, as the last node. 
      $record -> paste ( after => $doc -> root -> last_child );
   }
}

#set output formatting (optional)
$doc -> set_pretty_print ('indented_a'); 

#print to STDOUT.
$doc -> print;

#write to output file too
open ( my $output, '>', 'combined.xml' ) or die $!;
print {$output} $doc -> sprint;
close ( $output );
```

This deliberately extracts the `Record` elements from the target XML, and just merges those between the documents. However it's a flexible approach - `xpath` is quite powerful, and is the XML equivalent of regex - but works better because it's context aware, where regex is not.